# Stringr replacing values that does not end with patern

Tags: stringr

I would like to ask how in stringr replace string that does not end with pattern.

for example

```
var = c("car.my", "bus.my", "train.our", "tv.our", "remove", "bycicle")
```

I would like to add ".nobody" to strings that DOES NOT end with "my" or "our"

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with stringr, but give this a go

```
for (val s in c) { 
  if(!endsWith(s, "my") | !endsWith(s, "our")) {
    s = paste(s, ".nobody")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, however this is not very clean code. I would prefere slightly simpler code